# How to interpolate expressions in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to use the `keys` expression in Terraform to grab a list of keys (from a map variable) and assign it to a local variable. Here is the code snippet:

```
 locals {
 project_name_list = keys(${var.project_map})
 }
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown token: 29:22 IDENT keys
```

Am I missing something here. Nowhere can I find an example of this expression. As bad as it is, even the official documentation does not help -https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/keys.html

HashiCorp has really done a bad job of elaborating the nuances of Terraform for beginners on their website.

Answer (score 3):

Terraform functions need to be wrapped in expression syntax to show that it's not a literal value: `"${}"`

So try this: `project_name_list = "${keys(var.project_map)}"`

The example in the documentation is written as though being run from the terraform command line, which already assumes the command is a HCL expression and doesn't require that syntax.

**UPDATE**

I said above that the expression syntax is to show that it's not a literal value.  It's probably more accurate to speak of it as [expression syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html) vs. [configuration syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html).  Configuration syntax is the first level of interpolation, which forms the basic structure of your terraform file with resource blocks, data blocks, etc.  The second interpolation level is expression syntax which is used to generate values used by your configuration.

Thinking of it in these terms makes better sense of the error message, `Unknown token`, because terraform is attempting to read it as a configuration key word.

I had compared it to a literal value because it's in the same position as where a literal value would be.

Comment: Tried that, but got this- `error parsing local value "project_name_list" at 29:22: parse error at 1:8: expected expression but found invalid sequence "$" `

Comment: I'd need to see your updated code to help you with that.  Do you have an unnecessary `${}` within the outer `"${}"`?  make sure you use `"${keys(var.project_map)}"` and not `"${keys(${var.project_map})}"`

Comment: My bad, the expression I had was `project_name_list = "${keys(${var.project_map})}"` . The above wrapper worked. Thanks!